# Joining polygons with same boundaries

Tags: qgis, polygon

Sorry if my question feel stupid but I'm a new QGIS 2.4 user. My shape is composed of 7 polygons which are supposed to be adjacent (ie sharing sharing same nodes). Would like to join the polygons by their nodes and make sure there is no space in between two polygons. is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to retain the boundaries between the polygons?

Comment: Yes, I want to retain the boundaries between polygons: i.e one shapefile with 7 different and adjacent polygons sharing the same boundaries.